# removing item from loop if value is true

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am new to javascript and looping through a list which display a full list,but if the property of object property is set to true, I don't want to display it. I cannot figure out what will go inside if loop, as `pop` or `delete` isn't working.

```
for (const user of users) {
                user.name = `${user.firstname}`;
                if (user.disabled === true) {
                    /* not sure what to do here*/
                }
            }
```

Comment: There's nothing in your code block displaying anything.  Are you saying it is already displayed, and you want to hide it?

Comment: @JeffMatthews it is display all list, but I do not want to load if the user.disabled === true

Comment: What is the issue with the code at the Question?

Comment: please add the array, the wanted result and the possible values of `disabled`. you may consider to check directly without a template.

Comment: So... you have another loop somewhere that is doing the displaying, right? Shouldn't it simply ignore users that are disabled? I'm not sure what this loop has to do with your problem.

Comment: @KevinB first loop display all, but I want to filter that list, to display only which has a disabled property is not set to true.

Comment: Ok, so, reverse the condition (`!==`) and put your display logic inside of it. No need for filters/reduce or anything.

Comment: @KevinB I did this,  for (const user of users) {
                    if (user.disabled !== true) {
                        user.name = `${user.firstname} ${user.lastname}`;
                    }
                } it works but my disabled still shows invisible like taking up space.

Comment: `user.name = 'whatever'` isn't display logic.

Comment: You haven't specified how this array is being used to cause anything to display. It's unclear.

Comment: @KevinB It is a API call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164131/discussion-between-nofel-and-kevin-b).

Answer (score 3):

You want to [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) new objects (adding a new property `name`).
But instead of looping over the array twice, you can use [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to filter and map the object on the same iteration.

Running example:

```js
const users = [
  {firstName: 'john', disabled: false},
  {firstName: 'jane', disabled: true},
  {firstName: 'moe', disabled: false},
  {firstName: 'doe', disabled: true},
];

const nextUsers = users.reduce((result, current) => {
  if(!current.disabled){
    result.push({
      ...current,
      name: current.firstName
    });
  }
  return result;
},[]);

console.log(nextUsers);
```

Comment: @Nofel is the above answers your question?

Answer (score 2):

From what you show in your code I assume you have an array of users with at least properties `name`, `firstName` and `disabled`.
What you can do is use the ES6 fully supported method `filter` in order to remove the objects from the array that doesn't comply with the property you want to check.
For that you loop the array with the method `filter`, checking if the property `disabled` is `false`.

```js
const users = [
  {
     name: "Name1",
     firstName: "firstName1",
     disabled: true,
  },{
     name: "Name2",
     firstName: "firstName2",
     disabled: false,
  },
];

const usersFiltered = users.filter(user => !user.disabled);

console.log(usersFiltered);
```

Note: This won't work in IE 8 or lower without a polyfill.

Comment: `Array#filter` method belongs to **`ES5`**. See this link: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.20.

Answer (score -1):

If you want more performant way, you can do both operations in a one way with [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
const filteredUsers = users.reduce((newUsersArray, user) => {
  user.name = `${user.firstName}`
  if (!user.disabled) {
    newUsersArray.push(user)
  }

  return newUsersArray
}, [])
```

Since `users` is an array, you can filter it out with

```
users.filter(user => !user.disabled).forEach(user => user.name = user.firstName)
```

So [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is a way to filter your array: if result of function that iterates over every object inside array is false, it will not be included to resulted array

[Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/foreach) iterates over all items and allows to change every item.